# The name 'Thread' does not exist in the current context

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, 2013, page-layout, resource-files

I am trying to use following code in my page layout to display text from resource file but getting error.

CODE

```
<%= SPUtility.GetLocalizedString("$Resources:NewsHeading", "myresourcefile", Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture.LCID) %>
```

ERROR

> The name 'Thread' does not exist in the current context

I am using SharePoint Designer 2013. How do I fix this error?

Comment: Try adding System.Threadingso that it looks like so: System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture.LCID

Comment: I did that and now it says "The type or namespace name 'Thread' does not exist in the namespace 'System' (are you missing an assembly reference?)"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try by adding the Threading namespace to the top of the page:

```
<%@ Import NameSpace="System.Threading" %>
```

Comment: Added namespace on top and now it says "The best overloaded method match for 'Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SPUtility.GetLocalizedString(string, string, uint)' has some invalid arguments"

Comment: This error is correct. Typecast the LCID from int to unit as
<%= SPUtility.GetLocalizedString("$Resources:NewsHeading", "myresourcefile", (Unit) Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture.LCID) %>

Comment: I think you meant Uint. Anyway I tried uint, UInt32 and System.UInt32 but it throws error with correlation ID f66c339c-3ab2-7045-9a29-2796be1c78d7. I then opened log file to check but this correlation ID is found in lot of places in that file and none of it seems relevant to the error. How do I pinpoint the exact location of this error in that log file? :(

Comment: u could either use ULS log viewer or manually search from the log file. U need to be patient and go through the error then u could get it.

Comment: Thanks man you helped me greatly. I learned about ULS log viewer today which helped in tracking the problem. I found out the actual error is "The Controls collection cannot be modified because the control contains code blocks...". I searched and found solution to use <%# %> instead of <%= %> and now I do not get any error on page but it doesn't display anything either. The area where it is supposed to display $NewsHeading is blank. Any idea what could be the cause of it?

Comment: Sorry Man...not getting ur context...what u are trying to achieve.

Comment: "<%# %>" is only used for binding expressions. Even though you don't get any errors - it won't do anything in your case. You have to stick to the "<%= %>" construction.